How to add rotated image(stamp) annotation to PDF using iOS PDFKit
Sample Project
I am adding stamp annotation to PDF file, its working fine when I don't rotate image but when there is rotation then annotation is getting clipped from corners. You can see this in attached image.

Here is the code to create ImageAnnotation
import PDFKit
import UIKit

final class ImageAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
    var image: UIImage
    var currentRotationAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    init(bounds: CGRect, image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: .stamp, withProperties: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        context.saveGState()
        let midX = bounds.midX
        let midY = bounds.midY
        context.translateBy(x: midX, y: midY)
        context.rotate(by: -currentRotationAngle)
        context.translateBy(x: -midX, y: -midY)
        
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return }
        context.draw(cgImage, in: bounds)
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}

This is how I am adding ImageAnnotation sticker to pdf overlay and then converting to annotation when user tap outside of annotation sticker view.
Code to add Image sticker view to PDF overlay
func addImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        var rect = frameForImage(image, within: overlayView)
        rect.origin.x = overlayView.center.x - rect.width / 2
        rect.origin.y = overlayView.center.y - rect.height / 2
        self.frame = rect
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.superview!.topAnchor, constant: 24),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -24),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.superview!.bottomAnchor, constant: -24)
        ])
    }

This method add actual annotation to PDFDocument
func addImageAnnotation(image: UIImage) {
        guard let imageView = firstView(type: UIImageView.self) else {
            return
        }
        let frameAfterMargin = CGRect(x: center.x - imageView.bounds.width / 2,
                                      y: center.y - imageView.bounds.height / 2,
                                      width: imageView.bounds.width,
                                      height: imageView.bounds.height)
        let viewFrame = overlayView.convert(frameAfterMargin, to: pdfView)
        let annotationBounds = pdfView.convert(viewFrame, to: pdfPage)
        let annotation = ImageAnnotation(bounds: annotationBounds, image: image)
        annotation.currentRotationAngle = rotationAngle
        pdfPage.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

You can access the sample project here to quickly try it out
Sample Project
